# How to Make a HTML Form Where Files can be Submitted.\

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm kind of new to HTML, (not totally) and I was wondering the easiest way to create an HTML form page where users can submit files to. I have tried looking up many pages and tutorials, but they don't seem like what I need. I would want something where someone can submit a file and give it a name and it sends it to a database or something. Does anyone have a webpage where I can find a tutorial (or a video)?

Sorry if this is off-topic in anyway.

Comment: if all else fails [You could always try READING THE MANUAL](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) _Its a radical idea I know, but!_

Comment: You're right.  It is off topic.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific on SO, this is a request for resources, rather than a question with a definite answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so what you wanna do is do a POST request.

```
<form method="POST" action="/addFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div>
    <label><h4>Name of file</h4></label>
    <input type="text" name="file_name">
  </div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input name="photo" type="file">
</div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

After this, you want to catch this route with at POST request, and handle the input. You can do this in javascript or php etc.

Checkout Node.js or Laravel - im a big fan of laravel, and Laracasts has the tutorials you are asking for, for free at laracasts.com

Check this out (Laravel - PHP): https://laracasts.com/series/build-project-flyer-with-me/episodes/5